# Protect audio files using PHP

Tags: php, audio

I want to protect files using PHP. Right now I have this code, which is able to provide resumable downloads:

```
$file_info = finfo_open();
$file_mime = finfo_file($file_info, $file_path, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file_size = filesize($file_path);
$file_time = filemtime($file_path);
$etag = md5($file_size . $file_time);

ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "Off");

header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Disposition: inline");
header("Etag: {$etag}");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", $file_time));
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");

if($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH"] == $etag) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
}
else {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $file = fopen($file_path, "r");

    if($_SERVER["HTTP_RANGE"]) {
        preg_match("/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/", $_SERVER["HTTP_RANGE"], $matches);
        $length = $matches[2] - $matches[1];
        fseek($file, $matches[1]);

        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: " . ($matches[2] - $matches[1]));
        header("Content-Range: bytes {$matches[1]}-{$matches[2]}/{$file_size}");
    }
    else {
        header("Content-Length: {$file_size}");
    }
    header("Content-Type: {$file_mime}");

    while(!feof($file) && !connection_status()) {
        echo fread($file, 8192);
        ob_flush();
        flush();        
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

This works fine for all types of files — except audio (and also video) files.

It works with Firefox, Safari throws an error (failed to load resource) but plays anyway, Chrome and Opera refuse to play anything. Internet Explorer downloads the audio file even though `Content-Disposition: inline` is set. When I manually set `Content-Type` from `audio/mpeg` to `audio/mpeg3` Chrome also downloads the audio file despite `Content-Disposition: inline` being set.

I have no idea why some browsers keep behaving like they do, am I missing something?